# How to use awk to filter entire blocks of a file?

Tags: awk, gawk

Example input:

```
void foo(void) {
  printf("hello\n");
}

// Split
void noon(void) {
  printf("lunch\n");
}

void bye(void) {
  printf("goodbye\n");
}
```

I want to either filter away all blocks that start with //Split:

```
void foo(void) {
  printf("hello\n");
}

void bye(void) {
  printf("goodbye\n");
}
```

Or filter for only those blocks:

```
// Split
void noon(void) {
  printf("lunch\n");
}
```

How would I do that?  Basically anytime it sees "// Split", that line and future output would be directed toward a second file.  And anytime it sees a line starting with "}", it should output that line as normal, but then future output would be directed back to the first file.

Comment: could be there nested statement like `void noon(void) {
  printf("lunch\n"); int a = 1; if (a == 2) { print "not equal 2"; }
}`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you on same.

```
awk '/\/\/ Split/{non_flag=1} !non_flag; /}/ && non_flag{non_flag=""}' Input_file
```

---

In case you want to print block which has `split` in it then following may help you on same.

```
awk '/\/\/ Split/{flag=1} flag;  /}/ && flag{flag=""}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Down voter, let me know the reason for the down vote here??

Comment: I like how simple this is, but I don't understand why this works to show the // Split parts: `awk '/\/\/ Split/{flag=1} flag; /}/ && flag{flag=""}' input` but this does not: `awk '/\/\/ Split/{split=1} split; /}/ && split{split=""}' input` ; awk gives me syntax errors after split.

Comment: Oh, figured it out: split is a built-in function to awk.  I just capitalized it and everything works.

Comment: Just curious, why did you write `flag=""` rather than `flag=0` ?  Both seem to work.

Comment: @jorgbrown, it is habit now, glad that it worked for you. actually speaking `flag=""` will help you in case you want to do checks on `if` condition side etc, let me know if any more queries are there, will be happy to guide here.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternate output files like this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        f=F[0]="ofile1"
        F[1]="ofile2"
    }
    /^[/][/] *Split/ || (c && /^}$/) {
        f=F[c=!c]
    }
    { print > f }
' inputs...
```

If you just want either part, you can make the printing block conditional on `c` and get rid of `f` and `F`.

Comment: Tried that but since f isn't necessarily initialized on the first line, I get the error "fatal: expression for '>' redirection has null string value"

So I changed it to this `awk 'BEGIN { c=0; F[0]="ofile1"; F[1]="ofile2" } /^\/\/ *Split/ || (c && /^}$/) { c=!c } { print >F[c] }' input` and it very nearly works.  But the closing } on the // Split section goes to the wrong file.

Comment: Good catch, defining `f` in the `BEGIN` block fixes that. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^\/\/ Split/' file
// Split
void noon(void) {
  printf("lunch\n");
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/^\/\/ Split/' file
void foo(void) {
  printf("hello\n");
}

void bye(void) {
  printf("goodbye\n");
}
```

To redirect the "Split" blocks to a new file named "splits" and print the rest to stdout would be this with GNU awk or mawk (and maybe some others):

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '
    { print > (/^\/\/ Split/ ? "splits" : "/dev/stdout") }
' file
```

or with any awk:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '
    { out = (/^\/\/ Split/ ? "splits" : "") }
    out { print > out; next }
    { print }
' file
```

Comment: Nice, but relies on there being a blank line to differentiate sections. But thankyou nonetheless, because as it happens in my case that might be a desirable feature...

Comment: Every answer you got relies on something about the data you showed us, e.g. the answer you accepted will fail given numerous possible contents of your input file (e.g. `}` within a string or a comment or a conditional block or a loop or ....). It's very important when posting questions to include truly representative data and in this case if there isn't always a blank line between blocks then you shouldn't always show a blank line between blocks in your example and ditto for every other construct you might care about for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases with one **`awk`** command (assuming that there won't be nested statements `function { ... { ... } ... }`):

```
awk -v pr_split=1 \
'/^\/\/ Split/{ f = 1; n = NR }
 NR != n+1 && /.+ {/{ f = 0 }
 f && pr_split;
 !pr_split{ if (f) next; else print }' file
```

---

- `pr_split` - variable, stands for "print split" section. Tells whether to only print `// Split` section(s) or everything but those

---

To print only `// Split` sections:

```
awk -v pr_split=1 ...
```

The output:

```
// Split
void noon(void) {
  printf("lunch\n");
}
```

---

To print everything but `// Split` sections:

```
awk -v pr_split=0 ...
```

The output:

```
void foo(void) {
  printf("hello\n");
}

void bye(void) {
  printf("goodbye\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If "Split" only occurs in the comments:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/Split/' file
// Split
void noon(void) {
  printf("lunch\n");
}
```

A bit more verbose, but more accurate:

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS= '$1 ~ /Split/' file
```

When the Record Separator is empty, each record is delimited by empty lines.

Comment: That is unnecessarily gawk-specific due to no space between `-v` and `RS=`. Change `-vRS=` to `-v RS=` then it'll produce the same output in any awk. You should tighten up the regexp to avoid false-matches when `Split` appears in other contexts though, e.g. `/^\/\/ Split\n/` or  simply `$1 == "// Split"`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good point about the space, regarding the precice RegExp to be used I won't go down that road, other answers have provided alternative expressions...

Comment: The other answers all have the wrong approach. You have the right approach but just too loose a condition. If the OP has a function named `void mySplitter()` then your code would incorrectly treat it as if it was the `// Split` comment. That;s fine though, I'll just write my own answer.